temporal folium polyLine
I am trying to plot folium polyLine with my dataframe.
I have this kind of data
Datetime Lat lon    Cars
2021-06-01 4.5  1.1 Car1
2021-06-01 4.8  0.8 Car1
2021-06-01 4.4  0.9 Car2
2021-06-02 4.7  1.0 Car2

I want to plot Folium.PolyLine but with temporal dimension like HeatMapwithtime.
Anyone can help me?
Thank in advance

Here is a simple example of how to do this:
import folium
import pandas as pd
from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson

data = {
    'Datetime': ['2021-06-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-06-02', '2021-06-02', '2021-06-02'],
    'Lat': [4.5, 4.8, 4.4, 4.7, 4.6, 4.9],
    'Lon': [1.1, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.2, 1.3],
    'Cars': ['Car1', 'Car1', 'Car2', 'Car2', 'Car1', 'Car2']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

grouped_data = {date: group[['Lat', 'Lon']].values.tolist() for date, group in df.groupby('Datetime')}

m = folium.Map(location=[4.5, 1.0], zoom_start=10)

features = [
    {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'LineString',
            'coordinates': coords,
        },
        'properties': {'time': date}
    }
    for date, coords in grouped_data.items()
]

TimestampedGeoJson({'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': features}, period='P1D', duration='P1D').add_to(m)

m

which gives you a map and the ability to slow down the visualization by determining the number of frames per second.

Update: Add lines </>
To add the lines, you need to slightly change the code:
import folium
import pandas as pd
from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson

data = {
    'Datetime': ['2021-06-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-06-02', '2021-06-02', '2021-06-02'],
    'Lat': [4.5, 4.8, 4.4, 4.7, 4.6, 4.9],
    'Lon': [1.1, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.2, 1.3],
    'Cars': ['Car1', 'Car1', 'Car2', 'Car2', 'Car1', 'Car2']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

grouped_data = df.groupby(['Cars', 'Datetime'])

m = folium.Map(location=[4.6, 1.0], zoom_start=10)  

features = []

for (car, date), group in grouped_data:
    coords = group[['Lon', 'Lat']].values.tolist()  
    if len(coords) > 1:  
        feature = {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'LineString',
                'coordinates': coords,
            },
            'properties': {
                'times': [date]*len(coords),
                'icon': 'circle',
                'iconstyle': {
                    'fillColor': 'red',
                    'fillOpacity': 0.6,
                    'stroke': 'false',
                    'radius': 6
                },
                'id': car
            }
        }
        features.append(feature)

TimestampedGeoJson(
    {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': features},
    period='P1D',
    duration='P1D',
    add_last_point=True,
    auto_play=False,
    loop=False,
    max_speed=1,
    loop_button=True,
    date_options='YYYY-MM-DD',
    time_slider_drag_update=True
).add_to(m)

m.save('timeline_map.html')
m 

Which will give somthiong like this:


Thank you so much. But how can I add the line of polyLine between two coordinates?
